# How can I search lookup value in SharePoint list (Modern site)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Can anyone help me on how to search "Partner Full Name" (#1), which are lookup values from "Partner List" (#2)? I use the Search this list box (#3).

[image]

Comment: Is this extended field in lookup or primary field in lookup?

Comment: @GaneshSanap it looks like extended field, as there's a link in "Partner Short Name"

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes, it is a extended field in lookup by selecting "Partner Short Name".

Answer (score 0):

I am able to search the value in extended lookup columns in list. You have to enter the complete *word* to search for values.

**Examples**:

1. I have searched "youtu" & I am getting results like:

   [image]
2. And when I search for "you", I don't get any results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Lookup field values are indexed and you can search these values as any other regular fields. SharePoint will also crawl dependant lookup values also if they are added to list.

Keep in mind that general search rules applies, like you should search for whole words or use wildcard expression in the end of the keyword (ex: standa*)

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement, if these lookup values were recently populated, please wait for SharePoint Online to crawl them on the backend.

Also,copy the full specific column value and enclose it in quotation marks to check whether it can be searched correctly.